# Need help: can anyone provide tor gateway?

Tags: orbot

My 3G connection speed is lower than 100kbps, and Orbot connection is taking too long.
I want to connect my Hidden service from Android, but due to this situation I can't.
Can someone open a Tor SOCKS5 port for me(and other people like me)?
I'm not talking about Tor Bridge. I want a open SOCKS5 proxy(Tor's).

So I could try direct connection to it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not question about Tor, but a hep request.

Answer (score 1):

Opening a SOCKS5 port, especially by a third party, is a bad idea.

Here are a few reason why it is a bad idea:

- The server you connect to knows the circuit you use.
- The server can manipulate the circuit you use. In fact it chooses it.
- SOCKS5 is not encrypted, http:// and other traffic can be read by third parties.
- Traffic send to or received from the SOCKS5 sever can be manipulated. Particularly, http:// and DNS can be manipulated easily.

The issues listed above are not an issue as long as the traffic doesn't leave your device. However, you do not want that socks proxy to be running on an untrusted host or connect to it via an untrusted network.

If you run a Tor server, please DO NOT provide SOCKS5 proxy access, it provides the user with a wrong sense of security.

An alternative might be using [Tor2web](https://tor2web.org/), it appears to be using https:// to ensure traffic can't be read or minipulated when passing through the Internet. You should be aware though that the provider of the service still sees the traffic and is able to manipulate it. IF YOU DEPEND ON YOUR CONNECTION TO BE PRIVATE OR SECURE, DO NOT DO THIS.

Answer (score -1):

It will ruin the whole conception/idea behind Tor: your connection and it's metadata will be literally public. In your case a VPN tunnel to your server can be **a testing-only** solution to check, but for production use I do recommend you to use Tor installed on your phone. About Orbot - yes, it's slow. But the workaround is to compile android from source and integrate tor into it on a system image level. If your phone has this capability to build an open-source android for it - then I do recommend you to try this: for one of my test cases it was a remedy, actually: Orbot was *very slow*, but when integrated into a system image - tor used to bootstrap in 30-60 seconds... I haven't researched the matter deep, but this approach was connfirmed to solve the issue by some of my contacts in their cases too.